# How to call Haxe compiled JS from outer JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, haxe

I have compiled my Haxe JS project, and it's working fine.
What I have in Haxe is a `Main` class.

Now, I need to call a static function from a Haxe-compiled `Main`. I tried to call it like this:

```
Main.init();
```

But I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Main is not defined

When I look in my compiled JavaScript script of Haxe I can see that `Main` is wrapped into something like that:

```
(function () { "use strict";

var Main = function() {
```

So, how to reach `Main` from external JavaScript code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `@:expose` metadata to make it accessible:

```
@:expose class Main
```

For more details, check out [Exposing Haxe classes for JavaScript](https://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-expose.html) in the Haxe Manual.